# How can we solve NaN conflict in java?

Tags: java, math, nan

`java

```
//5.   Write a program to read three sides of triangle and print area for valid data and to print “Invalid data”
// if either one side of the triangle is greater or equals to the sum of other two sides.
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class EX_05 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter three sides of a triangle : ");
        double a = n.nextDouble();
        double b = n.nextDouble();
        double c = n.nextDouble();
        double s = (a+b+c)/2;
        if((a>=(b+c)) || (b>=(a+c)) || (c>=(b+a)) ){
            double area = Math.pow((s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)), 0.5);
            System.out.println("The area of triangle is " + area + ".");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid data");
        }
    }
}
```

`
I wanted to conclude whether the sides of triangle is valid or not to calculate area of triangle.

[image]

Here is the output shown by IDE.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please [edit] your question to include your source code and outputs as text instead of pictures.

Comment: Unrelated but `Math` has a perfectly working [`sqrt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)) method

Comment: It is hopefully obvious that a triangle (in Euclidean space) can't have sides of lengths 10, 5 and 2.

Comment: Like that @Srikanth Chakravarthy said, your conditions must be changed from > to < and from || to &&

Comment: Please draw me a triangle with these side lengths, and tell me what the area should be. Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a math question, not a programming question; and because it seems to expect the program to come up with a numeric answer in a case where that doesn't make any logical sense.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your condition is inverted. You always perform the calculation if the data is invalid and always print "invalid data" if the data is valid.

You should switch what you have in the else with what you have in the if.

Another option would be to add a ! in front of the entire condition.
Yet another would be to invert the logic of the entire condition.

Beyond that, the title of your question is completely unrelated to the actual problem. And please don't paste images of code. They hate that here on stack overflow. Its no fun re-typing all of someone's buggy code on your own machine just to help them find the problem. Post the code itself so it can be easily copied and tested.

Answer (score -1):

Your condition, to check whether the sides form a valid triangle, is wrong. Please correct that and you should get a proper value for area.

Comment: Probably, someone that think you response is out of scope

Comment: Not my down-vote, but your answer is so short and brief as to be obtuse (pun intended!). Perhaps more explanation would help.

Comment: It was my mistake and thanks for your time guys.